# App.use() necessary on only certain browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I was just setting up a project and trying to set up a favicon. For some reason I require **app.use** on chrome, but not on any other browsers. I am unsure as to why.

```
root - server.js, views, images
views - index.ejs 
images - yuhyuh.png
```

This is the basic layout of what I have right now
I have rendered index.ejs and I was trying to set up a favicon which I did using

```
<link rel="icon" href="/images/yuhyuh.png">
```

and for some reason it wasn't showing up at all on chrome, so I used this snippet I found online without really understanding what it really does or why it is even necessary at all

```
app.use("/images", express.static('images'));
```

It worked, but I realized that when I delete this piece the favicon still shows up on every other browser except for Chrome. I tested Microsoft Edge, Firefox, even Opera GX. Is this line necessary, is it showing up because I am locally hosting? I am unsure as to whether I need to keep this and why it occurs.

I tried to read into the documentation of `app.use()` and it referenced middleware, I understand that this is running the image through `express.static?` To showcase images within my express function, but to my understanding ejs is just html mixed up with js and this would not be required when rendering an html page, so I dont see why it is necessary now. I apologize if this seems like a question I can easily google, most of those sources left me more confused than not.

Comment: It probably gets cached by a browser. Try clearing cache or using the private mode.

Comment: clearing cache and using private mode did not help